# Ng-click is not working with ng-bind-html in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get the data with using Jsonresult and Angularjs in MVC4.

**Jsonresult function in the Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetQuestionSets() {
//...
var selectedData = titles.Select(y => new
{
    //...
    qsAction = y.qtConfirm.Equals(false) ? "<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' ng-click='getQSetId(qset.qsTitleID)'>Edit</button>" : y.Questions.All(z => z.qStatus == null) ? "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm disabled'>Waiting</button>" : y.Questions.All(z => z.qStatus == true) ? "<button class='btn btn-success btn-sm'>Preview</button>" : "<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'>Edit</button>",
});

return Json(selectedData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

**AngularJS to get result:**

```
$http.get('/Tutor/GetQuestionSets').then(function (response) {
$scope.questionSets = response.data;
});
$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml;// Convert string to html
```

**View:**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    //...
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="qset in questionSets">
        //...
        <td align="center" ng-bind-html="trustedHtml(qset.qsAction)"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**My question is:**

Ng-click which is coming through the json result `<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' ng-click='getQSetId(qset.qsTitleID)'></button>` not working. But when I change the ng-click to onclick with simple function its working. Do you know why and solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-bind-html` deals with pure DOM and not Angular directives like `ng-click`. Angular  has no idea about to include `ngClick` to digest cycle and therefore listen on events. You need to [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) it 1st. Or use [angular-bind-html-compile](https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile) that will do both things in one place

Comment: Thank you for answer :) angular-bind-html-compile solved my problem